# Android Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to inflate an activity with 2 `Fragments`. **Error:**

I want to inflate both fragments so they will display on the view. Even though I keep getting the error that I can not inflate the view.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragmentat android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
at aa.tuuts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Code:**

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sampleMethod(){
}
```

}

**Fragment One:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void sampleMethod();
    }
}
```

**Fragment Two:**

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

//    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    public FragmentTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
//        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
//            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
//        } else {
//            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
//                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
//        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
//        mListener = null;
    }
}
```

Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="aa.tuuts.MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="aa.tuuts.FragmentOne"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentOne"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_one" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="aa.tuuts.FragmentTwo"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTwo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentOne"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_two" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want to show two fragment on activity one by one...right?

Comment: ok...android:name="aa.tuuts.FragmentOne".....Check FragmentOne package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. It's weird.

I built your code and it works fine.

So please clean the code and rebuild. Perhaps some errors happened in build process. If it's not ok, close Android Studio and restart.

Hope it help you !